# Помогите с SQL запросом, SUM

Tags: mysql, sql, запрос

Нужно вывести товар – общий вес товара по всем поставкам;

Дошел до того, что смог написать запрос только для того случая, когда товар постачался только один раз. Если поставка была произведена более 1 раза - то пишет что Подзапрос возвращает более 1 записи.

Ниже оставлю код, нужно помочь с тем как дописать, что-бы количество всех поставок (Quantity ) суммировалась

```sql
SELECT Name , 
       Weight * (SELECT Quantity 
                 FROM `deliveries` 
                 WHERE deliveries.Article = goods.Article) AS AllWeight, 
       Unit 
FROM `goods` 
WHERE Article IN (SELECT Article 
                  FROM `deliveries`);
```

Так выдаёт ошибку:

```
SELECT Name , 
       Weight * (SELECT SUM(`Quantity`) 
                 from deliveries 
                 Group By Article 
                 WHERE deliveries.Article = goods.Article) AS AllWeight, 
       Unit 
FROM `goods` 
WHERE Article IN (SELECT Article 
                  FROM `deliveries`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Name
        ,Unit
        ,SUM(Weight * Quantity) AS AllWeight
FROM goods AS G
JOIN deliveries AS D ON G.Article = D.Article
GROUP BY Name, Unit
```